# Using multidimensional array to create table - Errror: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays, datatable

I'm trying to create a table using javascript and arrays. I'm making client side calls to SharePoint to return XML responses which gives me my data (users/groups). Using those calls I got an array of all my users and all my groups. I need to loop through each group and find the users in it, if the user is in that group, mark with an X, if not leave blank. I'm having trouble getting it working.

This is what I'm trying to make:

[image]

```
//Build taxonomy

var allGroups = ["Users"];
var allUsers = [];
var taxonomy = [];

function initTax(){
  console.log("initiating taxonomy...")
  //get all users and add them to array
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserCollectionFromSite",
    async: true, 
    completefunc: function(xData,Status){
      $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function(){
        allUsers.push($(this).attr("userLoginName"));
      });
    }
  });

  //get all groups and add them to array
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromSite",
    async: true,
    completefunc: function(xData,Status){
      $(xData.responseXML).find("Group").each(function(){
        allGroups.push($(this).attr("Name"));
      });
    }
  }); 
  buildTable();
}
var i, j;
function buildTable(){
  for (j=0;j<allGroups.length;i++){
    for (i=0;i<allUsers.length;i++){
      $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
        userLoginName: allUsers[i],
        async: true,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status){
          var userInGroup = $(xData.responseXML).find(allGroups[j]);
            if(userInGroup){
              taxonomy[j][i] = "X";
            }else{
              taxonomy[j][i] = "";
            }
        }
      });
    }
  }  
}
```

XML: GetGroupCollectionFromUser and GetGroupCollectionFromSite

```
<GetGroupCollectionFromUser xmlns=
       "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
       <Groups>
          <Group ID="3" Name="Group1" Description="Description" OwnerID="1" 
             OwnerIsUser="False" />
          <Group ID="15" Name="Group2" Description="Description" 
             OwnerID="12" OwnerIsUser="True" />
          <Group ID="16" Name="Group3" Description="Description" 
             OwnerID="7" OwnerIsUser="False" />
       </Groups>
    </GetGroupCollectionFromUser>
```

XML: GetUserCollectionFromSite

```
<GetUserCollectionFromSite xmlns=
   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
   <Users>
      <User ID="4" Sid="S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-
         34577" Name="User1_Display_Name" 
         LoginName="DOMAIN\User1_Alias" Email="User1_E-mail" 
         Notes="Notes" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
      <User ID="5" Sid="S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-
         354403" Name="User2_Display_Name" 
         LoginName="DOMAIN\User2_Alias" Email="User2_E-mail" 
         Notes="Notes" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
         .
         .
         .
   </Users>
</GetUserCollectionFromSite>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774422(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: can put some of the xml code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to divide the work into 5 functions, of which 3 of them simulate the request to the server and process the xml using jquery. The other 2 are responsible validating the data and build table. [See this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TEmtC/).

this is my js code:

```
/*
    Simulate get requesto to the server
*/
var getGroupCollectionFromUser = '<GetGroupCollectionFromUser xmlns='
  + '"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">'
  + '<Groups>'
  +'<Group ID="3" Name="Group1" Description="Description" OwnerID="1" OwnerIsUser="False" />'
  +'<Group ID="15" Name="Group2" Description="Description" OwnerID="12" OwnerIsUser="True" />'
  +'</Groups></GetGroupCollectionFromUser>';

var getGroupCollectionFromSite = '<GetGroupCollectionFromSite xmlns= '
  +'"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">'
  +'<Groups>'
  +'<Group ID="3" Name="Group1" Description="Description" OwnerID="1" OwnerIsUser="False" />'
  +'<Group ID="15" Name="Group2" Description="Description" OwnerID="12" OwnerIsUser="True" />'
  +'<Group ID="16" Name="Group3" Description="Description" OwnerID="7" OwnerIsUser="False" />'
  +'</Groups></GetGroupCollectionFromSite>';

var getUserCollectionFromSite = '<GetUserCollectionFromSite xmlns='
   +'"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">'
   +'<Users>'
   +'<User ID="4" Sid="S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-'
   +'34577" Name="User1_Display_Name" '
   +'LoginName="DOMAIN\User1_Alias" Email="User1_E-mail" '
   +' Notes="Notes" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />'
   +'<User ID="5" Sid="S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-'
   +'354403" Name="User2_Display_Name" '
   +'LoginName="DOMAIN\User2_Alias" Email="User2_E-mail" '
   +'Notes="Notes" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />'
   +'</Users></GetUserCollectionFromSite>';

var userGroupTable = {};
var users = [];
var groups = [];

function parseUserColl (){
    //simulate the get request to the server
    var dom = $(getUserCollectionFromSite);
    //process all user name
    dom.find('User').each(function(e){
        users.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
} 

function parseGroupColl (){
    //simulate the get request to the server
    var dom = $(getGroupCollectionFromSite);
    //process all group name
    dom.find('Group').each(function(e){
        groups.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
} 

function parseGroupCollFromUser (user){
    //simulate the get request to the server
    var dom = $(getGroupCollectionFromUser);
    var userGroups = [];
    //process all group name
    dom.find('Group[Name]').each(function(e){
        userGroups.push($(this).attr('Name'));
    });
    //return all the groups of the user
    return userGroups;
}


function processAll(){
    for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
        userGroupTable[users[i]] = {};
        var userGroups = parseGroupCollFromUser(users[i]);
        for(var j=0; j<groups.length; j++){
            //if the array userGroups contains the current group, the value must be true
            userGroupTable[users[i]][groups[j]] = userGroups.indexOf(groups[j]) > -1;
        }
    }
}

function buildTable (){
    //build header
    var header = "<tr><th>USERS</th>"
    for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i++){
        header += "<th>"+groups[i]+"</th>";
    }
    header += "</tr>";

    $("#table-data thead").append($(header));
    //build table body
    for(var user in userGroupTable){
        var row ="<tr><td>" + user + "</td>";
        for(var i=0; i<groups.length; i++){
            var groupName = groups[i];
            var $td = "<td>"+userGroupTable[user][groupName]+"</td>";
            row +=$td;
        }
        row += "</tr>";
        //append the data to the table
        $("#table-data tbody").append($(row));

    }
}

parseUserColl();
parseGroupColl();
processAll();
```

and my html code :

```
<button class="btn" onClick="buildTable()">Build Table</button>
<table class="table" id="table-data">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I hope that will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this. It's exactly what I am trying to do and works perfectly with my code.